# How to setup OpenWRT to enable access to DLNA servers across subnets

Tags: networking, openwrt, dlna

I have two routers, LAN to WAN.

Primary router runs OpenWRT, other is an ASUS RT-N66U.

I now have a RaspberryPi on the network with MiniDLNA. Unfortunately, the TV connected to the ASUS router cannot see this DLNA server.

ASUS is on IP 192.168.0.10 with its own DHCP for stuff on that side of the network, in the 192.168.1.x range

In OpenWRT:

`/etc/config/network` contains amongst other entries:

```
config interface 'lan'
    option ifname 'eth1'
    option force_link '1'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option ip6assign '60'
    option ipaddr '192.168.0.1'
    option igmp_snooping 1


config route
    option interface 'lan'
    option target '192.168.1.0/24'
    option gateway '192.168.0.10'
```

ifconfig:

```
br-lan    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D4:CA:6D:1B:3F:94  
          inet addr:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d6ca:6dff:fe1b:3f94/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fd8a:8723:5b8b::1/60 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7542487 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13666226 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:799347954 (762.3 MiB)  TX bytes:18695009301 (17.4 GiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D4:CA:6D:1B:3F:93  
          inet6 addr: fe80::d6ca:6dff:fe1b:3f93/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13936911 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7666052 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1639255174 (1.5 GiB)  TX bytes:938993450 (895.4 MiB)
          Interrupt:5 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D4:CA:6D:1B:3F:94  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7591107 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13663886 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:922993879 (880.2 MiB)  TX bytes:1514915277 (1.4 GiB)
          Interrupt:4
```

How do I get it so that the TV can see the DLNA on the other subnet?

I've tried avahi, igmpproxy and other fiddling to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

The default firewall rules for OpenWRT block the multicast packets from flowing from the WAN side to the LAN side.

If you turn the OpenWRT firewall off (`/etc/init.d/firewall stop`)and turn off multicast_snooping (`echo 0 > /sys/devices/virtual/net/br-lan/bridge/multicast_snooping`) then it should see the DLNA server. This works for me at least.

I haven’t worked out what firewall rules are responsible yet though.