# Why is DLNA not visible for clients connected to an Asus router set to AP mode?

Tags: router, routing, dlna

I have a DLNA server on a computer connected wired to a main router running OpenWRT (no special rules, no subnets, no VLANs, quite basic configuration).

A second router, an Asus AC1200, is connected wired to said first router using the WAN port and in the user interface it is set to work in AP mode, which should, in theory, just plainly connect WAN to LAN without filtering of any kind. It offers no DHCP and IPs are assigned by the main one because this second router has devices I want to reach from the remaining network as well.

The devices connected either wired or wireless to said Asus cannot see the DLNA server. If I however move the link connection from WAN to any of the LAN ports, DLNA appears again, so the workaround is found.

So there must be some filtering which blocks DLNA for data passing through the CPU of the Asus router.

I read in [How to setup OpenWRT to enable access to DLNA servers across subnets](https://superuser.com/questions/912715/how-to-setup-openwrt-to-enable-access-to-dlna-servers-across-subnets) that this kind of WAN-LAN filtering is happening also on other routers.

Is it normal and if so why that routers in AP mode filter data WAN-LAN this way? IMHO they should act as a plain network-wireless bridge, without any further interference to the data traffic.

Comment: Did you see if your ASUS router has an IGMP Snooping feature that you can disable, as suggested by the other question/answer you linked to? If DLNA service is advertised/discovered via multicasts, IGMP Snooping could get in the way.

Comment: @Spiff There is no such option, but I think it is rather the other way around: if IGMP snooping were available, no firewall filter to blindly drop all multicast packets would be needed, and the AP mode would work as expected. I think there is no IGMP snooping (for whatever reason) and to avoid flooding the wifi (see https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/dumbap#disable_daemons_persistently1 ) the decision was to drop everything. No idea.

Comment: The standard behavior of a bridge is to forward multicasts and broadcasts, not block them. IGMP Snooping is a way for a bridge to be selective of which multicasts it forwards. I suppose it's possible that they didn't want to forward multicasts BUT they for some reason didn't want to enable IGMP Snooping either, so they just outright blocked multicasts somewhere, but that would be a weird design choice.